# In Apache does the .htaccess file override the httpd.conf for mod_rewrites?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my Apache `httpd.conf` file I have this declaration inside a `VirtualHost` tag.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.shanestillwell.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shanestillwell.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And this inside my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The rule in my `httpd.conf` seems to be ignored. Are the rules in `.htaccess` wiping out the `httpd.conf` rewrite rule?

Answer (score 4):

Generally your settings in .htaccess file inside a directory overrides httpd.conf file settings. You can disable this effect by editing your httpd.conf file and change the following line

```
  <Directory ...> 
  AllowOverride all
```

to

```
    <Directory ...> 
    AllowOverride none
```

This will prevent .htaccess file from overriding httpd.conf settings. So the settings in .htaccess file will have no effect.

Comment: I have `AllowOverride All`, but I think in this case it's because the .htaccess catches the request and redirects it before it hits the rules in the http.conf file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557040/in-apache-does-the-htaccess-file-override-the-httpd-conf-for-mod-rewrites-clos

Comment: "Generally your settings in .htaccess file inside a directory overrides httpd.conf file settings." - this statement is false (or at best misleading) without further information/context. The question is specifically discussing mod_rewrite. The _mod_rewrite_ directives in the `.htaccess` file will only override the _mod_rewrite_ directives in `httpd.conf` if the directives in `httpd.conf` are also in a `<Directory>` container. Unfortunately, this has not actually been stated in the question. The _context_ in which these directives are used is everything.

Comment: "This will prevent .htaccess file from overriding httpd.conf settings. So the settings in .htaccess file will have no effect." But what if I want the rules in .htaccess to be applied too? i.e. I want to merge the two rulesets.

Answer (score 3):

> In Apache does the .htaccess file override the httpd.conf for mod_rewrites?

Taken literally, the answer is "No". However, ...

> In my Apache `httpd.conf` file I have this declaration inside a `VirtualHost` tag

If it really is *directly* inside the `<VirtualHost>` container, ie. in a *virtualhost* context, then these mod_rewrite directives should override the mod_rewrite directives in your `.htaccess` file - not the other way round. This behaviour cannot be changed (eg. by changing mod_rewrite inheritance with the `RewriteOptions` directive).

However, if these directives are inside a `<Directory>` container (which is inside your `<VirtualHost>` container), ie. in a *directory* context (as opposed to a *virtualhost* context, as suggested above), then the mod_rewrite directives in your `.htaccess` file will indeed completely override the mod_rewrite directives in your `<Directory>` container. However, this behaviour *can* be changed by changing the way mod_rewrite directives are inherited. (By either setting `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` in the `.htaccess` file, or `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore` in the parent `<Directory>` container. `InheritDownBefore` requires Apache 2.4.8. However, there are other caveats with mod_rewrite inheritance to be aware of.)

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

The behaviour you are seeing (and the specific syntax of the directive used (see below) - although this might simply be a mistake if the code has never been executed?) suggests these directives are in a *directory* context, not a *virtualhost* context. So yes, the mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess` will completely override the parent directives - the mod_rewrite directives in the `<Directory>` container are effectively ignored.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

If this was used in a *virtualhost* context then you'd get an erroneous double slash at the start of the URL-path, because in a *virtualhost* context the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the full URL-path (which includes a slash prefix). So the `$1` backreference itself would already contain a slash prefix before including an additional slash in the *substitution*.

However, in a *directory* context, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against a partial path - a filesystem path less the directory-prefix (which ends with a slash) - so the path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* never starts with a slash in a *directory* context (so you need to include it in the *substitution* - like you have done).

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `<Directory ...>` with `AllowOverride all` then whatever you have on your .htaccess file will be replacing any previous rule.

It could be in your `httpd.conf` or on your `virtualhost` as long as it point to `/` or to your domain path.